# How can I tell if I'm at the last result when using WHILE so that I can omit a comma from my output?

Tags: while-loop

I know I can do what I need to do by getting a total records count and if I'm at the last record, don't display a comma but there has to be a better way.

I'm trying to build an SQL statement programatically using values from MySQL.

The code:

```
$fql="SELECT ";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT field FROM fb_aa_fields WHERE fql_table = '$query'", $conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $get_field = "".$row{'field'}."";


$fql = $fql."$get_field, ";

}

$fql = $fql."FROM ".$query." WHERE owner=".$get_uid."";
```

It outputs this:

SELECT aid, can_upload, cover_object_id, cover_pid, created, description, edit_link,  link, location, modified, modified_major, name, object_id, owner, photo_count, size, type, video_count, visible, FROM album WHERE owner=522862206

The problem is the last comma between "visible" and "FROM".  How would you suggest is the best way to make that comma go away?

Answer (score 0):

It's less of a pain to detect whether you're at the first element than the last.  You could do like

```
$i = 0;
while($row =...) {
    if ($i++) $fql .= ',';
    $fql .= $row['field'];
}
```

Or, possibly better, defer tacking on fields to the string til the end.  There's a built-in function called `implode`, that you can use to insert the commas between them.

```
$fields = array();
while($row =...) {
    $fields[] = $row['field'];
}
$fql .= implode(',', $fields);
```